# Android Studio- starts with 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I searched through the site but could not find an answer so here is my question.
I am using Android Studio 3.6 and when I start a new project and choose Basic Activity there are two fragments appearing in layout. So in layout there are .xml files activity_main,content_main,fragment_first and fragment_second. Therefore, when I start a new project, I get a different screen than the usual "hello world" screen. To add, I cannot basically edit the fragments. So, how can I back to "normal" and start without these fragments?

Comment: Create   empty/blank project

Comment: Why do not you create Empty Activity instead of Basic Activity?. When creating a new project make sure that you select Empt Activity instead of Basic.

Comment: I was watching a tutorial which was choosing basic activity which ends up with hello word. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a basic activity, you basically create an activity with two fragments. this means that basic activity by default provides two fragments that you can edit and use. basically, it's almost the same with bottom navigation activity. the difference is only in basic activity there is no bottom navigation.

if you want to make one activity app. you don't really need to use fragments. so you can just make a Empty activity instead of basic activity. if you want to make your activity fragmented in the future, you can add it later.